# continously differentiable imply uniform Lipschitz wrt parameter

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, derivatives, solution-verification, lipschitz-functions

Consider $g$ continuous on $[a,b]\times \mathbb{R}^n$, $[a,b]\subset \mathbb{R}$, and
$x\mapsto g(t,x)$ continuously differentiable for all $t\in [a,b]$.

I wonder if $g$ is Lipschtz wrt to $x$ that is for every compact $K\subset [a,b]\times \mathbb{R}^n$, there exists a constant $L_K\ge 0$ such that  for all $(t,x)\in K$, $(t,y)\in K$, we have
$$
|g(t,x) - g(t,y)|\le L_K|x-y|
$$

---

I wrote
$$
g(t,x) - g(t,y) = (x-y)\cdot \int_0^1 \frac{\partial g}{\partial x}(t,y+s(x-y))d s
$$
and then using Cauchy-Schwarz,
$$
|g(t,x) - g(t,y)|\le |x-y| |\int_0^1 \frac{\partial g}{\partial x}(t,y+s(x-y))d s|
$$
and from the continuity of $x\to \partial_x g$, there exists $C(t)$ such that :
$$
|g(t,x) - g(t,y)|\le C(t)|x-y|
$$

However it seems that nothing ensures that $C$ is bounded for  $t$ such that $(t,x),(t,y)\in K$ or am I missing something ?

**EDIT** : I am looking for an counter-example.

How about $g(t,x) = tx^3\sin(1/(tx))$ ?

we have for $0<y<x$:
$$
C(t)\ge\frac{tx^3\sin(1/(tx)) - ty^3\sin(1/(ty))}{x-y} 
\ge \frac{x^2-y^2-1/(6t^2)}{x-y} = x+y-\frac{1}{6t^2(x-y)}
$$
Clearly $C(t)$ is not bounded.

However this doesn't show that my question is wrong.

Comment: Do you want lipschitz or only locally lipschitz? If $K$ is compact, then $C(t)$ is certainly bounded when $t\in K$ because of the https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extreme_value_theorem

Comment: Lipschitz with respect to the definition I gave.
To apply this theorem $C$ needs to be continuous. Why does ensure the continuity of $C$ ?

Comment: Do you mean $\sin(1/t^2x)$? Seems like a good example, then.

Answer (score 0):

Take  $g:[-1,1]\times \mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}$ defined by
$$
g(t,x)=\sqrt{t} x^2\sin(\frac{1}{tx})
$$

Clearly $g$ is continuous on $[-1,1]\times \mathbb{R}$ and $x\mapsto g(t,x)$ is continously differentiable ($\partial_x g(t,x) = 3 \sqrt{t} x^2 \sin \left(\frac{1}{t x}\right)-\frac{x \cos \left(\frac{1}{t
    x}\right)}{\sqrt{t}}$).

Take $K=[-1,1]\times [1,2]$ and $(t,x), (t,y)\in K$.
By the mean value theorem that there exists $c\in [1,2]$ such that
$g(t,x)−g(t,y)=\partial_x g(t,c)=3 \sqrt{t} c^2 \sin \left(\frac{1}{t c}\right)-\frac{c \cos \left(\frac{1}{t
    c}\right)}{\sqrt{t}}$.
Clearly this diverges for $t>0$ small enough and any value of $c$ in $[1,2]$. Hence the statement cannot be true.

Comment: I missed this when I commented, but you need $\sqrt{|t|}$ … Or the modification I suggested. And of course you need $g(t,0)=g(0,x)=0$ in both cases.